# cannot detect already loaded referenced assembly

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I am making some program that needs to implement a plugin structure. `Loader.exe` is the main application, `Plugin.dll` is a plugin class library. `Plugin.dll` requires `Depend.dll`.

I want to force load `Depend.dll` in a specific path, without GAC or appdomain base directory, etc. I preload the `Depend.dll` using `Assembly.LoadFile` before loading `Plugin.dll`, but assembly cannot detect loaded `assembly-Depend.dll`. It throws:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException at Plugin.Start()

Is it possible to preload referenced assembly without adding event handler to AssemblyResolve?

I cannot use AssemblyResolve handler.

**Depend.dll**

```
using System;

namespace Depend
{
    public class Hello
    {
        public void World()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Plugin.dll**

```
using Depend;

namespace Plugin
{
    public class Plugin
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            new Hello().World();
        }
    }
}
```

**Loader.exe**

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(path, "..\\Depend.dll"));
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(path, "Plugin.dll"));

Type typ = asm.GetType("Plugin.Plugin");
typ.GetMethod("Start").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(typ), null);
```

Comment: Why can't you use AssemblyResolve?

Comment: You can use private proobing paths by specifying multiple paths relative to your application directory. The runtime then will then look for assemblies in these paths as well. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can i forcing to fire AssemblyResolve? I don't want to load Depend.dll located in GAC. Depend.dll must be loaded in current AppDomain.